# Schedule routes with a specific order with Camel and Quartz 2

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I want to schelude routes in a spceific order using Apache Camel and Quartz 2.
I defined a context adding two routes:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {

            from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=5").startupOrder(1).setBody().simple("Current time is "+new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())).to("stream:out");
            //from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=5").setBody().simple("Current time is ${header.firedTime}").to("stream:out");

        }
    });

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {

            from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=5").startupOrder(2).setBody().simple("Current time is "+new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())).to("file:C:\\Users\\milioli\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CamelWithQuartz\\data\\out.txt");
        }
    });

    context.startAllRoutes();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();

}
```

The code builds and runs but I have no feedback from console where I expect the result of the route with order 1. Furthermore the route with order 2 doesn't write on the file passed as argument. Each route, taken individually run correctly.
Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you have to name each job individually like: myTimerName1 and myTimerName2 ... then both routes can be declared

Comment: Yes, yesterday I solved it

Comment: If my answer is the real solution, then perhaps you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create unit test before starting to code and even use them for development of the Camel route (as long you can mock endpoints).

The following test show that you can use two Quartz schedulers if there are named differently:

```
package org.ruffp.camel.quartz;

import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class QuartzEndpointTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:DESTINATION")
    private MockEndpoint mockDestination;

    @Test
    public void testQuartz() throws Exception {
        resetMocks();
        mockDestination.expectedMessageCount(3);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {

        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                //@formatter:off
                from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerNameOne?trigger.repeatInterval=100&trigger.repeatCount=1")
                    .setProperty("test").constant("This is the job 1")
                    .to(mockDestination);

                from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerNameTwo?trigger.repeatInterval=100&trigger.repeatCount=0")
                .setProperty("test").constant("This is the job 2")
                .to(mockDestination);

                //@formatter:on
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you put the same name for both (e.g `myTimerName`) the test will not pass but the route definition does not throw any error/exception.